# Is it normal for an app to request update without disclosing its name?

Tags: windows-10-mobile, security, system-apps, app-update

I constantly check for updates and I have found mysterious app request update. I tried many times to know to what is it by long press on it to get some information about this app. All I can do about it either cancel, or postpone the update process. FYI I'm very picky about the apps I install on my phone. I suspect it is a malicious app but I retracted later and told myself maybe it is a system app and don't stop it.

Has anyone of you encountered a similar issue like this?

- Windows 10 Mobile
- Lumia 640 XL

[image: Unknown app request update]

Comment: these are just small bugs , it would be fixed when store is restarted or when rechecked for updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Has anyone of you encountered a similar issue like this?

Yes, I have encountered a similar issuea on my Windows 10 mobile multipe times. It happens sometimes.

> I suspect it is a malicious app

It's just a normal app updating. It is the store which has failed to load details.

**Solution**

To solve this you need to restart the store and recheck for updates.

Answer (score 2):

For me this usually happens for internal / Microsoft apps - no worries.